# DOMPDF output to server not showing text when using Dejavu font

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, dompdf

Had one of you ever problems when you save a PDF on the server with DOMPDF and if you want to look/open the PDF on the server, afterwards don't see characters but blocks instead?

**I have the following for output.**

```
//Download PDF
$dompdf->stream("Invoice: ".$row['number'].".pdf", array("Attachment" 
=> true));
//save the pdf file on the server
file_put_contents('uploads/'.$row['number'].'.pdf', $dompdf- 
>output());
```

**And this for styling:**

```
*{ font-family: DejaVu Sans;}

@font-face {
      font-family: "DejaVuSans";
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      src: url('fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
```

Comment: The font-family has a space in it in the css, but not in the font-face.

Comment: @MrLister No thats not the problem

Comment: That is 100% part of the problem. If you declare a custom font, you can only load that font by using the exact same `font-family` that you told the browser to use for that font asset. So if you define the `@font-face` rule as `font-family: DejaVuSans;` then your page CSS _must_ use `font-family: DejaVuSans;` if it wants to actually use that webfont. (And note that quotes are not necessary until you add symbols or spaces)